# Multiple reps if $g$ not conjugate to $g^{-1}$

Tags: representation-theory

If $g \in G$ is not conjugated to $g^{-1}$, how do I prove that $G$ has irreducible non-equivalent representations of the same order? I think the multiple representations are going to be in some way conjugate (I'm thinking like how there can be multiple Sylow-p subgroups for a given p), but how do I show that a sort of parallel representation must exist in this case?